# Apache Requests per second

Tags: php, apache, optimization, nginx, centos

I have installed `centos6` + `apache` (backend) + `nginx` (frontend) + APC. And if benchmark it using the command:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://domain.com/index.html

Server Software:        nginx/1.0.15
Server Hostname:        domain.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /index.html
Document Length:        1423 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.109 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1730000 bytes
HTML transferred:       1423000 bytes
Requests per second:    9173.81 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       10.901 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.109 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          15498.72 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   1.5      1       6
Processing:     3    8   2.4      8      16
Waiting:        1    7   2.9      7      16
Total:          6   10   1.8     10      17

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     10
  66%     11
  75%     11
  80%     11
  90%     13
  95%     13
  98%     14
  99%     15
 100%     17 (longest request)
```

I got `9173.81` requests per second, but if use command:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://domain.com/index.**php**
```

Which is the same file content, but `*.php` extension.

```
Server Software:        nginx/1.0.15
Server Hostname:        domain.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /test.php
Document Length:        902 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.277 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1109000 bytes
HTML transferred:       902000 bytes
Requests per second:    783.38 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       127.652 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.277 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          848.41 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    2   4.8      0      18
Processing:     4  122  34.7    138     162
Waiting:        2  122  34.8    138     162
Total:         21  123  33.4    139     168

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    139
  66%    150
  75%    151
  80%    152
  90%    159
  95%    161
  98%    162
  99%    162
 100%    168 (longest request)
```

I got `783.38` requests per second. Why so much difference in score? It’s an identical file.

Comment: It's the same file processed differently. Send an envelope using DHL and a regular mail. The same mail - but it will be delivered at different times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because `index.html` is a straight HTML file & is basically just tossed off of the server immediately after being requested.

In contrast `index.php` is a PHP file that Apache must parse & depending on the contents this can be a simple or complex task but will always be more “expensive” to deal with than a straight HTML file request.

Comment: thx for answer, can u say it's normally for my config or not:
CPU 1x2Ghz
RAM 2Gb
Bandwidth 100Mb/s